# Programmatically close ListPicker from WP7 Silverlight Toolkit

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, windows-phone

My app is being rejected from the Marketplace because of requirement 5.2.4.c (back button must close menu or dialog and cancel back navigation). I'm using a ListPicker from the Silverlight Toolkit and that's what's causing the failure: pressing the back button when the ListPicker is open goes back instead of closing the ListPicker and cancelling back navigation.

This seems simple enough to fix: if the user presses the back button and the ListPicker is open, I close it and cancel back navigation. However, I haven't seen a way of programatically either detecting whether a ListPicker is open, or closing a ListPicker.

Am I missing something? How could I fix this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One again, I have asked the question too soon. The answer is here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7643

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    if (yourListPicker.ListPickerMode == ListPickerMode.Expanded)
    {
        yourListPicker.ListPickerMode = ListPickerMode.Normal;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```